# How to ship applications with some preferences set to a set value

Tags: iphone

I have one preference in my application that I want my app to be "shipped" with, how do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone shed some light on why my answer was voted down?

Comment: See comment on your answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an NSDictionary then use

```
[myDict setObject:@"defaultvalue" forKey:@"mykey"];
```

for each of your default values.  Then use

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:myDict];
```

It is safe to always do this on startup as it won't overwrite settings.  When you go to read the value for your settings via

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mykey"];
```

you will get your default value, or the value that you subsequently set.

Comment: thank you! After some tries this was what I came up to also:)

Comment: where do you see that `registerDefaults` won't overwrite existing settings? I don't find that in the documentation.

Comment: registerDefaults is the standard apple way, it works like this: Your app requests the value for a default, the defaults object checks the plist on disk, failing that it goes to the values you set for register defaults, failing that it returns nil.

Comment: @kubi - In the User Defaults Programming Topics: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/UserDefaults/Concepts/DefaultsDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000718-97046 : "The registration domain is a set of application-provided defaults that are used unless a user overrides them..." I use this all the time and it works as advertised.  It will not overwrite any user defaults that have been specified on disk or through any other means.

Comment: @Brad Beautiful! That's going to simplify some stuff for me.

Answer (score 1):

Store this preference in your app bundle as part of some set of defaults. When your app launches for the first time (an no saved preferences exist) save this value to NSUserDefaults, the documents directory, or where ever you store your app's preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing set in the defaults for a given key, set something. You can do this check whenever your app loads, at any time after the first run, you'll always have an object for your `@"MySpecialPref"` key.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![defaults objectForKey:@"MySpecialPref"]) {
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"MySpecialPref"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also ship it with a default SQLite database that contains custom values, and use them in your app

Comment: I did not vote down, but probably because of a rather cumbersome way of achieving what I asked for.